# Support for XHTML documents?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, xhtml-1.0-strict

Something funny happens when you serve an XHTML document as XHTML "application/xhtml+xml" as [recommended](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/NOTE-xhtml-media-types-20020801/).  **AJAX libraries, scripts, and styles seem to fall apart.**

jQuery's documentation for individual methods is littered with comments about lack of support for XML documents like:

> "Note: this method currently does not provide cross-platform support
>   for setting data on XML documents, as Internet Explorer does not allow
>   data to be attached via expando properties."

or the more direct

> "This method is not available on XML documents."

[Mozilla also mentions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_JavaScript_for_XHTML) that "document.cookies does not exist in XML documents" and "document.write is not supported in XML documents".  Meanwhile, [there's a final recommendation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/properly_using_css_and_javascript_in_xhtml_documents) to "not use inline style or script in XHTML" at all.

**This lack of support/features for XML/XHTML documents (with MIME type "application/xhtml+xml") in AJAX libraries and browsers is disappointing and alarming.**

Where can I find an overview of how handicapped the jQuery API is when working with XHTML documents?  Or perhaps a comparison of features available on the document object between an HTML document and a properly served strict XHTML document?

Comment: Just curious, why are or would you use the "application/xhtml+xml" MIME type?

Comment: That is the proper/recommended way to serve an XHTML document (you know, the stuff ASP.NET renders).  It is also one of the main content types accepted by modern browsers like firefox, second only to the MIME "text/html" type.  See section 5.1 (http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/), which is normative (http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/#normativedef).  The only time you should serve an XHTML document as "text/html" is if you following the HTML compatibility guidelines in Appendix C (http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines), but that forces you to break the XML document in some ways.

Comment: Here (http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/NOTE-xhtml-media-types-20020801/), it's stated very clearly: *"This document summarizes the best current practice for using various Internet media types for serving various XHTML Family documents. In summary, 'application/xhtml+xml' SHOULD be used for XHTML Family documents, and the use of 'text/html' SHOULD be limited to HTML-compatible XHTML 1.0 documents. 'application/xml' and 'text/xml' MAY also be used, but whenever appropriate, 'application/xhtml+xml' SHOULD be used rather than those generic XML media types."*

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.webdevout.net/articles/beware-of-xhtml

Comment: Wow, that's really sad.  It's a little outdated, as IE 9 supports XHTML parsed as XML with the "application/xhtml+xml" content-type just fine.  I think HTML is a joke, and the way these guys cave in, saying "well, HTML is how most people do things now, so let's just stick with it".  That's very, very sad.  They miss the whole point that tag soup sucks, and supporting it simply encourages it.  HTML 5 should have been abandoned for strict XHTML 2, and the DOM for XHTML needs to include the "cookies" element and a "write" method that would support inserting a well-formed XHTML string.  Lame.

Comment: "The guy who made CSS." What, it was made by one guy?  So we're relying on the opinion of one guy to determine the future of the web, because he said "I don't think XHTML is a realistic option for the masses. HTML5 is it."  That's crazy talk.  Anyway, I think the following quote says it best and I have to agree with her at this point based on this sad lack of support for XHTML: "I'm an advocate of using XHTML only in the correct way, which basically means you have to use HTML. Period." - Anne van Kesteren

Comment: The sick thing is that ASP.NET renders XHTML, and since we really must serve HTML and use the "text/html" content-type, what's really happening is we're now in a position where we're forced to serve content that is neither valid HTML nor XHTML, but rather this hybrid tag-soup monstrosity.

Comment: In any case, XHTML 2 resources and ideas have been handed over to HTML5, which supports XHTML-like closing tags, is in the xhtml namespace, and even has a proper XML serialization XHTML5... so I'm looking towards XHTML5 now.

Comment: @Triynko I think a lot of your complaints have been resolved by now (document.cookie for example), perhaps it would be best to remove this question?

Comment: "The guy who made CSS". Yes, it was one guy: Håkon Wium Lie, the CTO of Opera Software

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm on the same track, but I've come across the following being used to assist XHTML/jQuery operations:

```
<a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js"/>
```

Hope this is of some use :)